# How to send data through api to elastic template? ie how to alter/change this envelope that I have for a regular template that works?

Tags: docusignapi

I cannot seem to figure out what the envelope definition for an elastic template looks like. Appreciate if I could get any guidance or a code sample. this was my previous envelope definition that I used.

edit---> please help me make sure syntax is correct (do i need to use access_token = self.access_token for example idk;i have a predefined variable called access_token and account_id). Do i need the version number? etc.

the fields on the elastic template itself are blank and the GOAL is to pass values to them and then email that consent agreement out to clients

```
'''
                    api_client = create_click_api_client( access_token) #n=args[access_token] )
                    clickwrap_request = ClickwrapRequest(status='active',fullName= 'Full Name', email=  'Email', 
                    company=  'Company',title=  'Job Title',date=  'Date',
                    companyName=  'company_name',
                    recipientEmail=  'recipient_email',
                    recipientBy=  'recipient_by',
                    recipientTitle=  'recipient_title',
                    recipientName=  'recipient_name',
                    senderName=  'senderName',
                    senderBy=  'senderBy',
                    senderTitle=  'senderTitle',
                    selectedConditionLogicForm=  'selectedConditionLogicForm')

                    accounts_api = AccountsApi(api_client) #may not need args
                    response = accounts_api.update_clickwrap_version(
                        account_id,
                        clickwrap_id=clickwrap["clickwrap_id"],
                        version_id=clickwrap["version_number"],
                        clickwrap_request=clickwrap_request,
                    )'''
```

I tried looking for sample code online but seem to be getting the same thing as above. Thanks in advance

Comment: You want elastic templates? the code above has nothing to do with elastic templates, but regular/eSignature templates that sends envelopes.

Comment: If you are confused about what you need, let me ask you this - do you need someone to sign/fill information or just say "OK" "Agreed" "Consent" and that's it?

Comment: @InbarGazit I need them to agree to consent. im working on multiple things and have the e signature figured out apart from the cc copy issue I posted about last week

Comment: now i want to use elastic template specifically to take advantage of the conditional logic feature that seems to be a lot better than on the esignature api. It will be the same inputs as the original but now being put into an elastic template rather than a regular template.

Comment: There's no conditional logic feature in Elastic template, you are confusing the terms. You  may not know this, but what you want is in eSignature API

Comment: I mean creating rules feature or whatever its called. I have some sample code on updating an elastic template look at edit. please let me know if i require any modules to import. im not sure on syntax either

Comment: You changed the code entirely, now it's using Click API, before it was using eSign API. What is the issue with this new code?

Comment: do i need any modules, does the syntax look right? From my understanding this does indeed update the blank fields in the template with values I am passing right? and this can then be mailed out CC recipient or just recipient?

Comment: really recommend that you get the DocuSign quickstart, full package (right-most) and choose Python, you will get code with all modules and configuration ready to work, just change it after it does eSign to use Elastic templates (from search )

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart

Comment: Also where do i find the elastic template id?

Comment: When you create it you get it back from the API in the call to create, or do you mean where to find it in the UI?

Comment: Click api does not seem to use any modules, can you confirm this? I ask because this will all need to go into an aws lambda file. theres way too many things in the quickstart and i can't tell what is helpful for me

Comment: UI cuz i already created it using a document

Comment: There's a REST API - it does use a module
If you only need to embed a clickwrap that was created and activated and managed via the UI - then you don't need any module (or any REST API) you just embed it in your page using HTML

Comment: can you send a link to this? 
what i understand is because I created an elastic template on docusign with fields and evertything, I do not need to do what I did above in the code? is this correct

Comment: And because all im doing is updating those fields that are premade, embeding this would be simplest what to update? Im also doing all this in AWS, so need to see if the embed option will even work lmao

Comment: Yes, but I still recommend you get the quickstart, it will do everything for you and you'll see how it works

Comment: ok can you send the link to a sample embed example and/or guide me to where it is in quickstart? sorry to ask but the quickstart has an overwhelming amount of files

Comment: Did you run the quickstart? did it work? let's not worry about the files yet

Answer (score 0):

Elastic templates are only managed via the Click API, the Click API is a REST API and it is used to create, remote, update, activate and create secure links for elastic templates (also you can get a list of all agreements signed with this template).

This is different than eSign API, Elastic Signing does not allow to put signature marks on documents, and is mostly used to agree to simple terms or something like that.

Now, you can have dynamic data with Elastic templates, that is done via JavaScript in the HTML code, not via REST API.

All of this is available via our [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/), but there are (In Python) different examples of what you can do from code.

If you already have your Elastic template ready to go then the "[How To Embed an  Elastic signing agreement](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/how-to/embed-elastic-templates/)" is what you need.

There's still a REST API call needed, but all of the code is in GitHub with the lead file you need - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-python/blob/master/app/click/examples/eg006_embed_clickwrap.py

Answer (score 0):

this is the code that works

```
clickwrap_request_body = {
            'status':'active','fullName':'recipient_name', 'email':'recipient_email', 
            'company':'company_name','title':'recipient_title',
            'companyName':'company_name',
            'recipientEmail':'recipient_email',
            'recipientBy':'recipient_by',
            'recipientTitle':'recipient_title',
            'recipientName':'recipient_name',
            'senderName':'senderName',
            'senderBy':'senderBy',
            'senderTitle':'senderTitle',
            'selectedConditionLogicForm':'selectedConditionLogicForm'
        }
clickwrap_url = f'https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/v1/accounts/{account_id}/clickwraps/{clickwrap_id}/'
 headers = { 
                'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
 update_url = f'https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/v1/accounts/{account_id}/clickwraps/{clickwrap_id}/' #/versions/{"V1.0"}
response = requests.post(update_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(clickwrap_request_body))
response = requests.get(clickwrap_url, headers=headers)
```